# Provide Dockerhub username and access token to Nextflow AWS Batch executor

Tags: docker, aws-batch, nextflow

I want to run my Nextflow pipeline using an AWS Batch executor. However, I pushed a private (not public) image to Dockerhub. When executing the Nextflow pipeline locally, I can access the local image.

However, when executing my Nextflow pipeline using the AWS Batch executor, the Docker image can't be accessed because it's private. Is there a way to provide a Dockerhub username and access token to my Nextflow pipeline so it can pull the private Docker image from Dockerhub?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Wave service to authenticate the access to the private container repositories. See the [nextflow docs](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/wave.html#authenticate-private-repositories) for more details

Answer (score 1):

You might also be able to use [AWS Secrets Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/secrets-manager/) to store the Dockerhub username and access token:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/how-to-authenticate-private-container-registries-using-aws-batch/